# Java: Run HTTP server on demand from my app?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, p2p

I want to write a **simple P2P** test app which uses HTTP as
underlying protocol.
The app has to **decide on demand**, if it should
act as a **HTTP server**, or as a **HTTP client**.

The classic way which I am aware of, would be to deploy the app on
some **existing** HTTP server. But this is the wrong way for my intention.
It has to be the other way: the server is started by the app (and only
if it decides to).

Is there a way to execute the HTTP server part **on demand**
(without deploying the app itself on a server)?

Can I do it by linking Glassfish or Tomcat libraries
and call some "main" method?

**Edit: IT WORKS!!!**
I now tried **Jetty** along with **JAX-RS (Jersey)** successfully!
Thank you all.

(the REST class is trivial and left out)

package my.p2p;

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.*;
import org.mortbay.jetty.*;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception {

    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);

    holder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass",
      "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
    holder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.p2p.rest");

    Server server = new Server(8000);

    Context context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(holder, "/*");
    server.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) or some other embeddable HTTP server. From Jetty's web site:

> Jetty is an open-source project providing a HTTP server, HTTP client and javax.servlet container. These 100% java components are full-featured, standards based, small foot print, embeddable, asynchronous and enterprise scalable. Jetty is dual licensed under the Apache License 2.0 and/or Eclipse Public License 1.0. Jetty is free for commercial use and distribution under the terms of either of those licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the other answers there also is [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/). Its very tiny, in just one class and maybe the right thing if yout don't need more or just want to keep things minimal.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [restlet](http://www.restlet.org) project. They provides an embeddable, standalone server, and a client, both using the same Java API (the famous Uniform Interface).

Glassfish, Tomcat or servlet API seems to be a little overkill to me. My 0.02$ :)

**EDIT**

*Client*

```
 Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);  
 client.get("http://127.0.0.1").getEntity().write(System.out);
```

*Server*

```
Restlet sayHello = new Restlet() {  
    @Override  
    public void handle(Request request, Response response) {  
        response.setEntity("Hello World!", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);  
    }  
};  

new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 80, sayHello).start();
```

Comment: I think Jersey is somehow similar to Restlet, right?
Can Jersey also be used? Thank you.

Comment: Jersey is the RI of Restful Services. I dunno if it provides client side, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 includes a built in web server. You can use it like so:

```
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange xchange) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            xchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = xchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    });
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
```

And then access http://localhost:8000 to see your response.

There are more examples in the JavaDoc for the [HttpServer package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html)

If you can't guarantee Java 6, take a look at [embedding Jetty 6](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) which is easy and fairly lightwight, i.e. you don't need a whole webapp.

Comment: It is not recomended to use internal com.sun.* or sun.* interfaces and classes, because they may be changed or deprecated at any time.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't apply on separate libraries of Sun, such as Jersey.

Comment: True, I should have specified "If you can't guarantee Sun Java 6", use Jetty instead.